# Spring security java config basic authentication filter

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I am trying to add basic authentication for my APIs where the users will be authenticated based on their credential stored in MongoDB. I want to use java config instead of XML based config. So far what I have learnt is I have to create `@Configuration` by extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and override `configure` method. In that I can add a custom filter by `addFilterBefore()`.

But how can I get a `Authentication` header information in the filter, how to proceed if the user is authenticated. I have been googling a lot but didn't find any good example that will help a novice like me whose been into spring just for 1 week.

Does any one have a good tutorial or sample that can help me get started with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As example, you can use next solution.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
    http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint());
}

@Bean
public BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint getBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint(){
    BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint basicAuthenticationEntryPoint = new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    basicAuthenticationEntryPoint.setRealmName("Basic Authentication");
    return basicAuthenticationEntryPoint;
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

}
```

It works for me. But you need to implement UserDetailsService interface.
Spring automatically checks is user authenticated and tries to proceed authentication if not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but like I said I am totally new to spring, so could you please share some detailed example or sample. Thanks